# HTTP request via NWConnection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, http, networking

I have the following setup:

- A laptop with a lightweight server running on it (Node.js/Express), let's say the server listens to the port 3000 and responds with some JSON to `GET /hello`.
- iOS app

The laptop and iOS device are connected into one local network via Ethernet cables. The server advertises itself on the network (using mdns node package) with the name, let's say, "simple.server".

The iOS app is able to discover this server with the help of Network framework:

```
// in the beginning of the class declaration
private var browser: NWBrowser?

func discoverServer() {
  let parameters = NWParameters()
  self?.browser = NWBrowser(for: .bonjour(type: "_http._tcp", domain: "local."), using: parameters)
  self?.browser?.stateUpdateHandler = { [weak self] newState in
    switch newState {
    case .failed(let error):
      self?.browser?.cancel()
    default:
      break
    }
  }                           
            
  self?.browser?.browseResultsChangedHandler = { [weak self] results, changes in
    for change in changes {
      switch change {
      case .added(let result):
        switch result.endpoint {
        case .service(let name, _, _, _):
          if name == "simple.server" {
            let connection = NWConnection(to: result.endpoint, using: .tcp)
            connection.stateUpdateHandler = { newState in
              switch newState {
              case .ready:
                if let innerEndpoint = connection.currentPath?.remoteEndpoint,
                  case .hostPort(let host, let port) = innerEndpoint {
                    let content =
                      "GET /hello HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                      "Host: \(host)\r\n" +
                      "\r\n"
                    let completion = ... just print an error if any
                    connection.receive(minimumIncompleteLength: 1, maximumLength: 10000) { content, _, _, _ in
                      if let content = content {
                        print(String(data: content, encoding: .utf8))
                      }
                    }
                    connection.send(content: content.data(using: .utf8), completion: completion)
                                                    
                                                    
 ... the rest of closing brackets are here
}
```

This successfully send HTTP GET request (and I assume would work for POST too, which I did not test yet), and receives response.

The problem is that response is a raw string, like this:

```
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nX-Powered-By: Express\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 215\r\nETag: W/\"d7-/V8YoIpwjOAIzkBGCymxNZtfrTw\"\r\nDate: Thu, 19 Oct 2023 12:58:08 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nKeep-Alive: timeout=5\r\n\r\n{\"items\":\" 1: \\\"something\\\"\\r\\n 2: \\\"something else\\\"\\r\\n 3: \\\"yet another one\\\"\\r\\n 4: \\\"and so on\\\"\\r\\n 5: \\\"and so forth\\\"\\r\\n 6: \\\"the end\\\"\\r\\n\\n\"}"
```

To make sense of such a response I would have to manually parse it (e.g. split by line breaks, parse out the response code, headers, body etc), which is a bit cumbersome.

So my question is: how do I make it better?

- Is there a way to parse it nicely into HTTPURLResponse?
- maybe there's a better way to do the request in the first place?
- Maybe I should not do it via NWConnection but somehow use URLSession after discovering the service?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Yes, you don't want to use an NWConnection. You want to use the `NWResult` to create a url

Comment: Hey @Paulw11 , do you have hints on how to do that?

Comment: You are already extracting the host and the port from the result: just use those values to create a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I succeeded in the end to send an HTTP request.

As @Paulw11 mentioned in comments, it is possible to build a URL with host and port that we have already parsed from `connection.currentPath?.remoteEndpoint`.

There're just couple of things to note:

1. The `host` is an ipv6 address (in my case; I tried to do the change on the server side to force ipv4, but it did not work; I did not dive deeper yet), so it should be enclosed into `[]`, which I totally missed. We can also switch on `host` to see if it's ipv4 or ipv6, and build the url accordingly.
2. For some reason `URLSession.shared.dataTask` call with completion never called the completion. But async one, `URLSession.shared.data(for:)`, worked perfectly (again, didn't even try to figure it out yet).
3. If arbitrary loads are forbidden in the plist, the request will fail. This is yet for me to tackle.

Here's the working code:

```
let urlString = "http://[\(host)]:\(port)/printers"
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
  Task {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let result = try? await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    print(result)
  }
}
```